# How to set LiveData<List<customType>> to MutableLiveData<List<customType>>?

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am developing in Android, and try to get the `LiveData<List<customType>>` via following function.

```
private fun getDataList(): LiveData<List<customType>> {
        return room.getData()
    }
```

And I create a parameter like the following:

```
private var customLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<customType>>()
```

How to set the `getDataList()` to `customLiveData`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have other sources for `customLiveData` as well?

Answer (score 1):

`LiveData<T>` **cannot** be set directly into `MutableLiveData<T>`. However, you can use the `value property` to set the value of `liveData` to `mutableLiveData`, like,

```
 customLiveData.value = getDataList().value
```

Comment: how is this the answer ? OP says they want to `set the getDataList() to customLiveData` and your answer does the opposite ?

Comment: My answer sets the `getDataList()` to `customLiveData` @a_local_nobody

Comment: Hmm, maybe i'm just misunderstanding, because you can set customLiveData to getDataList() but not the other way around